# i'm having trouble to understand this least upper bound proof

Tags: real-analysis

i'm recently found a proof  showing that Q does not obey the least upper bound axiom, here's the link: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m320/qsup.pdf

the proof breaks down into three steps, but I just don't undestand the algebra behind the 1st and 2nd steps:
from the fist step:" To ensure that q > α we
choose q to be of the form α + ε with ε a strictly positive rational number. For q to be in
E, we need to choose ε small enough that
$$q^2 = (α + ε)
^2 = α^2 + 2αε + ε^2$$
is smaller than 2. We already know that α ≤ 2 and we may always choose ε to be smaller
than, for example, 1. Then

$$q^2 ≤ α^
2 + 4ε + ε = α
^2 + 5ε$$"and this part from step 2:" To ensure that ˜q < α we choose ˜q to be of the form
α − ε with ε a strictly positive rational number. We choose ε small enough that
$$q˜
^2 = (α − ε)
^2 = α
^2 − 2αε + ε
^2$$
is larger than 2. As α ≤ 2, we have −2αε ≥ −4ε so that
$$q˜
^2 ≥ α
^2 − 4ε + ε
^2 > α^2 − 4ε$$"

my question is: How $q^2 = (α + ε)
^2 = α^
2 + 2αε + ε^2$ became $q^2 ≤ α^
2 + 4ε + ε = α^
2 + 5ε$ and $q˜
^2 = (α − ε)
^2 = α
^2 − 2αε + ε
^2$ became $q˜
^2 ≥ α
^2 − 4ε + ε
^2 > α^2 − 4ε$  ??? what's the algebraic procedure there?? maybe the answer it's ridiculously simple but I just can't see it.

thanks.

Comment: Pleae use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of doing COPY + PASTE from a PDF. As a result, for instance, in several places you have $\alpha2$ where you should have $\alpha^2$.

Comment: In the first one, $q^2=(\alpha+\varepsilon)^2=\alpha^2+2\alpha \varepsilon + \varepsilon^2$. But $\alpha \leq 2$ and $\varepsilon \leq 1$, so $2\alpha \varepsilon \leq 4 \varepsilon$ and $\varepsilon^2 \leq \varepsilon$. The second one is basically the same.

Comment: $0< \epsilon < 1$ so $0< \epsilon^2 < \epsilon$.  $\alpha < 2$ so $2\alpha \epsilon < 2*2*\epsilon = 4\epsilon$ so $\alpha^2 + 2\alpha\epsilon + \epsilon^2<\alpha^2 + 4\epsilon + \epsilon = \alpha^2 + 5\epsilon$.

Comment: And for the second $2\alpha\epsilon  < 4\epsilon$ so $-2\alpha\epsilon > -4\epsilon$ so $\alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon > \alpha^2 - 4\epsilon$.  And $\epsilon^2 > 0$ so $\alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon + \epsilon^2 > \alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon > \alpha^2 - 4\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: "and we may always choose ε to be smaller than, for example, 1"

The assumption that $0 < \epsilon < 1$ is essential.

That means $0 < \epsilon^2 < \epsilon$.

And we also have $0 < \alpha < 2$.

Hence:

1)  $$(\alpha + \epsilon)^2 =$$ $$\alpha^2 + 2\alpha\epsilon + \epsilon^2 <$$ $$\alpha^2 + 2*2*\epsilon + \epsilon =$$$$\alpha^2 + 5\epsilon$$

And

2) $$(\alpha - \epsilon)^2 =$$ $$\alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon + \epsilon^2 >$$ $$\alpha^2 - 2*\alpha*\epsilon + 0 =$$$$\alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon >$$$$\alpha^2 - 2*2\epsilon=$$$$\alpha^2 - 4\epsilon$$

====

Okay, let's do this a different way.

$0 < \alpha < 2;  0 < \epsilon < 1$

so

$0*(2\epsilon) < \alpha*(2\epsilon) < 2*(2\epsilon);  0*\epsilon < \epsilon*\epsilon < 1*\epsilon$.

so

$0 < 2\alpha*\epsilon < 4\epsilon; 0 < \epsilon^2 < \epsilon$.

so

$\alpha^2 < \alpha^2+2\alpha*\epsilon < \alpha^2 + 4\epsilon; 0<\epsilon^2<\epsilon$.

so

$\alpha^2 + 2\alpha*\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < \alpha^2 +4\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < \alpha^2 + 4\epsilon + \epsilon$

so

$(\alpha + \epsilon)^2 < \alpha^2 + 4\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < \alpha^2 + 5\epsilon$

so

$(\alpha + \epsilon)^2 < \alpha^2 + 5\epsilon$

Meanwhile.

$-2 < -\alpha < 0$

so $-2(2\epsilon) < -2\alpha\epsilon$

$\alpha^2 - 4\epsilon < \alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon; 0 < \epsilon^2$

$\alpha^2 - 4\epsilon < \alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon < \alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon + \epsilon^2$

$\alpha^2 - 4\epsilon < \alpha^2 - 2\alpha\epsilon + \epsilon^2 < (\alpha - \epsilon)^2$.

Comment: i'm still don't understand  from where you get  this $\alpha^2 + 2*2*\epsilon + \epsilon$..

Comment: Why not? $(\alpha + \epsilon)^2 = \alpha^2 + 2\alpha*\epsilon + \epsilon^2$ right?  And $\alpha < 2$, right? and $\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$, right?.  So $\alpha^2 = \alpha^2$ and $2\alpha\epsilon < 2*2\epsilon$ and $\epsilon^2 < \epsilon$, right? ANd if $a = a$ and $b < x$ and $c < y$ then $a + b +c < a + x + y$, right?  So $\alpha^2 + 2\alpha\epsilon + \epsilon^2<\alpha^2 + 2*2\epsilon + \epsilon$, right?  Where's the problem?

Comment: aahhhh. now I got it, I didn't took in mind that property (inequalities),thank you very much!